# IFrame Detection for Cross-Origin Pages

Tags: iframe

I'm working on a web app that contains iframes whose sources are from different domains. I want to be able to detect whether or not a website will load successfully in an iframe.

I've tried a bunch of solutions I've found here, none of which seem to work. I've tried setting a timer and then checking the content of the iframe (which won't work because of the same-origin policy). I've tried performing a GET request to the source of the iframe, but a lot of domains won't let you do this even if the iframe loads up.

From my understanding, whether or not it loads is determined by the X-Frame-Options, but I don't think I have access to that either because I cannot get the HTTP response headers.

Is this just impossible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add specific code that you have tried. While this isn't my area of expertise, you might want to look into `ChromeDriver`, which is used for automated WebApp testing. Although, I am not sure if your final use case is a website that tests if you can iFrame a particular site or if you simply want to know if a particular site can be iFramed. It might help to add a little more background about your motivation for this.

Comment: I am working on a web app where users have to make comparisons between two websites. If it will not work with an iframe, I'd like to remove the iframe.